# Why signed numbers comparisons can't be done only with sign flag

Tags: fasm

So I did a program that reads two inputs a and b and compares a to b if a is bigger returns 1 if b is bigger or equal it returns 0 only using sign flag. I'm supposed to be using the overflow flag but I haven't been able to find a test case where overflow flag is needed

BITS 32

%include    'training.s'

global main
extern  exit

; ===============================================
section .text

```
; The program begins here:
```

main:

```
    call    read_hex  ;;;this function reads an input from shell    
    mov     ecx,eax 
    call    read_hex
    sub     eax,ecx
    js      b1
```

s1:

```
    call    print_eax ;;;this function prints in shell value in eax
    mov     eax,0
    call    print_eax
    jmp     c1
```

b1:

```
    call    print_eax ;
    mov     eax,1
    call    print_eax
    jmp c1
```

c1:

```
; Exit the process:
push    0
call    exit
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found a test case 8000 0000 and 0FFF FFFF makes sets the overflow flag  and the output is not what expected